# Do inline Javascript events decrease web page loading performance?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom-events

Does  inline Javascript code like this below:

`<div onclick='javascript:some_function();'></div>`

grow up web page's loading time in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The browser must fire up a separate Javascript parser for each attribute.

It is more efficient to bind the events to functions using `attachEvent` / `addEventHandler`, or, more easily, jQuery.

---

On an unrelated note, you shouldn't use `javascript:` in an event attribute (aside from the fact that you shouldn't use event attributes at all).  It's just an unused label.
In `href` attributes, the `javascript:` *protocol* allows you to create a URI that executes Javascript.  However, event attributes take a string of Javascript code, not a URI.